# Microsoft Edge as markdown default program

Tags: windows-10, file-association, microsoft-edge

On Windows 10, I like to use Edge and the chrome extension Markdown Viewer to view Markdown (.md) files.  Currently I just drag the files into Edge.  Now I want to set Edge as my default for opening these file types.

Currently it's set to use a program called "Code Writer".  So, I right click the markdown file, choose:

> Open With -> Choose another app -> More apps -> Look for
>   another app on this pc

At this point I browsed to the Edge executable located in this location:

> C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

a path I found mentioned in this question [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/how-to-locate-microsoft-edge-program-file-exe/d6abbd8a-0a6c-47c9-ad95-28bdb36ec39e).

The .md file now shows the Edge icon as if it's the default program and the control panel file associations now shows edge as well:
[screenshot of md file association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q23ZC.png)

But when I double click these markdown files, nothing happens, Edge doesn't open.  How else can I set Edge to open my markdown files?  Is this the wrong executable?